# iPad: how can I create a repeatable UI element using Interface Builder?

Tags: ipad, ios4, interface-builder

I want to make a panel in Interface Builder with buttons and stuff on it.  Then I want to programmatically clone it and reposition the clones with affine transforms.

I'm thinking of something like a MovieClip from Flash.

[image]

And it isn't sufficient to just render the same UI element multiple times.  For example, it should be possible to type something different in each text box.

Any ideas?

Comment: I mean, have you tried already? Are there any problems? You can easily create viewControllers with an associated xib's view by using `[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"foo" bundle:nil];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new NIB file that contains your custom view.
2. Create a `UINib` instance from that NIB file with `+[UINib nibWithNibName:bundle:]`.
3. Whenever you want to create a new view, call `-[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]`. The array that this method returns contains all top-level objects of your NIB. So if the NIB file you created only consists of a view, the array contains this view as its only element. Make sure to retain the objects in the array.

Comment: Thank you!  For others: I put that code in the main ViewController's viewDidLoad method.  Use [self.view addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:0]] to display the first view in the array.

Comment: @nialsh What argument are you passing to [UINib instantiateWithOwner: ... ]?

Comment: I'm asking because I get the following run-time exception: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSObject 0x4e25bd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageView.'