# Custom Look And Feel of a text field in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikit, uitextfield

I'm a beginner with Objective-C and have a question regarding creating a custom look and feel text box. I want to be able to create a text box area that has, for example a header with a label and different background color etc. where the text input appears. How does one go about doing such a thing in Objective-C? Is it a matter of just creating a custom class that has a `UILabel` with specific coordinates on top of the UITextBox? Let me know if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to create a custom view that contains a UITextField and UILabel as sub-views.  After that, the view can be re-used.

I highly recommend reading the View Programming Guide @ Apple:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

A related post on creating an aggregate custom view:  [.Net UserControl XCode equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699384/net-usercontrol-xcode-equivalente)

Here's one tutorial on creating a custom view:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1768/how-to-make-a-custom-uiview-a-5-star-rating-view

You can also look at how other custom controls are built.  Many of the controls at cocoacontrols.com are open sourced:  http://www.cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use layer property of text field like

```
@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UITextfield *email;
```

so in implementation file or view did load method

```
self.email.layer.backgroundColor = [uicolor orangeColor];
```